# Python saving value as an instancemethod instead of integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, a-star, grid-search

So, I am currently writing a program that randomly generates a grid maze. The following code segment is the class definition of a single "cell" of the grid. I have defined 2 getter methods `get_row` and `get_col`, which can retrieve the coordinates of the cell. I believe this is where the issue lies.

```
class cell: #Node storing each cell of grid
    def __init__(self, rowNum=None, colNum=None):
        self.rowNum = rowNum
        self.colNum = colNum
        self.blocked = 0 # 0 denotes False, all cells are initially unblocked
        self.f = 0 # Distance from start node
        self.g = 0 # Distance from goal node
        self.h = 0 # Total cost ( h = f + g )
        self.parent = None
    def get_row(self):
        return self.rowNum
    def get_col(self):
        return self.colNum
    def isBlocked(self):
        if self.blocked == 0:
            return 0
        if self.blocked != 0:
            return 1
```

Then, I use the following segment to traverse the grid and randomly determine certain squares as the start and end. I save these coordinates as `start_row`, `start_col`, `end_row`, and `end_col`.

```
# List containing all the unblocked cells
unblockedCells = [cell() for i in range(numUnblocked)]

start_row = -1
start_col = -1
end_row = -1
end_col = -1

# Randomly picks 2 unblocked cells to be the starting and ending point
def set_start_and_end():
    global start_row
    global start_col
    global end_row
    global end_col
    ctr1 = 0
    for i in range(totalRows):
        for j in range(totalCols):
            if cellsArray[i][j].blocked == 0:
                unblockedCells[ctr1] = cellsArray[i][j]
                ctr1 = ctr1+1
    
    #Initialize start position
    startIndex = random.randint(0,len(unblockedCells)-1)
    start_row = unblockedCells[startIndex].get_row
    start_col = unblockedCells[startIndex].get_col

    #Initialize target position
    endIndex = random.randint(0, len(unblockedCells)-1)
    end_row = unblockedCells[endIndex].get_row
    end_col = unblockedCells[endIndex].get_col

    print("Start: (",start_row,", ",start_col,") End: (",end_row,", ",end_col,")")

set_start_and_end()
```

However, when I try to access the values of `start_row` and `start_col` later in the program, I receive the error `list indices must be integers, not instancemethod`

**My question is, why are start_row and start_col being stored as instancemethod and not as integers?**

Comment: `unblockedCells[startIndex].get_row` is an instance method. You need to acutally call the mehtod using `()` i.e. `unblockedCells[startIndex].get_row()` is the returned value from your instance method (i.e. an int). Alternatively you can decorate your getter with `@property` and then you won't need the `()`. Although your getter methods are pointless since `self.rowNum` etc are public members. Also don't use `global`. Also your code snippet has a ton of variables that don't appear to be assigned to anywhere?

Comment: thank you, so should I just use unblockedCells[startIndex].rowNum instead? Could you perhaps explain more how to use @property

Comment: See my answer. But yes, you should just use `unblockedCells[startIndex].rowNum` as those functions are pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a small snippet to illustrate the different options

```
class Cell:
"""Doc strings go here btw, not as comments. Also take a look at pep8 naming conventions: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions"""
    def __init__(self, row_num = None, col_num = None):
        self.row_num = row_num # A public instance member - you can get and set this directly without the need for function
        self._col_num = col_num # A private member. By convention, you should not get or set this directly
    def get_row(self):
    """This is a method, you need so call it using parenthesis i.e. .get_row()"""
        return self.row_num
    @property
    def col_num(self):
    """This is property being used to expose a private member. You don't need parenthesis to call it."""
        return self._col_num


my_cell = Cell(1, 2)
print(my_cell.row_num)  # row_num is a public member, you can just access it directly
print(my_cell.get_row)  # get_row is a method, so this will print the actual function
print(my_cell.get_row())  # this calls the function and prints the integer
print(my_call.col_num)  # because of the property decorator, we don't have to call this function but can treat is as if it was a member. But note it would be weird to name it get_... now as verbs imply functions.
```

In your case I would just use a public instance member. There is no need for any of your functions. In fact this whole object looks like it could just have been a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple
class Cell(NamedTuple):
    row: int
    col: int
    blocked: bool
```

or if you're using python>=3.8 a [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Cell:
    row = None
    col = None
    blocked = False
```

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful